# Android and Node.js hashed passwords do not match

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, hash

In my Node.js application the passwords are hashed and stored in the DB using [bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt-nodejs).

```
bcrypt.hashSync(password); //i am not using salt
```

I am coding an Android application which will connect to that database, where users have to login.

The password hash is calculated as follows:

```
String pwd = "usergivenpassword";
try {
     MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
     md.update(pwd.getBytes("ASCII"));
     byte[] sha1hash = md.digest();

     StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
     for (byte b : sha1hash) {
          int halfbyte = (b >>> 4) & 0x0F;
          int two_halfs = 0;
          do {
              buf.append((0 <= halfbyte) && (halfbyte <= 9) ? (char) ('0' + halfbyte) : (char) ('a' + (halfbyte - 10)));
              halfbyte = b & 0x0F;
          } while (two_halfs++ < 1);
      }

      String hashedPassword = buf.toString();

      Log.i("PWD", "-------------- hashedPassword: " + hashedPassword);

} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

However the end result is not the same as the hash stored in the db. Even when I use SHA-1 and MD5, the hashed string do not match.

For example, if I hash my name "neeraj" with bcrypt, like

```
bcrypt.hashSync("neeraj");
```

It gives

> $2a$10$UxHJfLSGZHOM15QEjGWadOfvEG9XBGO5/oe.bBI4W0NGjhaZ9N0FO

With Android's method it gives:

> fd60e9a01ba7409dca2fc97abdc69d92877b85d90307c0b0982397355ed32ff5

What is Android's equivalent of Bcrypt node.js?

Also should I just hash it on Android side and send it to my node server

OR

Encrypt the password with AES192 > send it to node.js server > decrypt it > hash it with bcrypt > compare

Any other suggestion is welcomed.

Comment: The fact that you can send the password to the server, then decrypt it, makes using a hash almost obsolete.  Once hashed, you should not easily be able to get the password back, that's the point of hashing. Rather hash and salt the password on the mobile then send that to the server to store it.

Comment: My approach was to just hash it on Android's side and send it to the server to compare.